# How to make text to wrap image in editor

Tags: jquery, css, editor, word-wrap

I have an editor on my page (Cleditor jquery plugin).

By default it can insert image, but text doesn't wrap it. I've tried vertical-align:top, but it didn't help:

[image]

What css I should point to image to get wrapped by text? You can try to do this in firebug on CLEditor [demo page](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/)

P.S. I've tried float: left, and it worked. But I should consider that it is editor, and user can move this image to right (and then it should be float: right, but how to catch when to switch float direction) - So I think, should be another decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WYSIWYG editors are no replacement for proper code. Some of the better ones have a CSS drop-down that will use your own stylesheets, allowing you select the image and select `float:left` (plus you probably want some margins too), or some custom CSS class.

In top of that you end up with things like `<b>this<b></b> is bold<b>` if you're not too careful. Overall, they're crap.

If you're using a standard layout, you may want to define something like this and allow the CSS to do the work instead of the editor.

```
.article img {
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px

}
```

When you give this level on control to an unskilled user you're likely to end up with unexpected results.

If you are comfortable with going into the HTML and making direct edits, you can ise custom CSS classes.

```
  .article img.left {
      float:left;
      margin-right:5px;
      margin-bottom:5px

    }

   .article img.right {
      float:right;
      margin-left:5px;
      margin-bottom:5px

    }
```

Then you need to add the class names to the img tag:

```
<img class="left" src="..." />
```

or

```
<img class="right" src="..." />
```

Comment: yes, i know that html code of wysiwyg editor+unskilled users is ugly code, but what I should to do then? I want users not to have deal with tags (BB-tags or html-tags - no matter).

Comment: about your css code. Yes, this code will help me. But then user's can't move image to the right (by pressing `enter` in front of image). How to integrate css code in to the editor's body - it's not a problem, i've found a way. But how to make images wrapped by text and from left and from right? (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You need to add custom classes to the mark-up in HTML view to do that. It is not something the client will likely be comfortable with. I will add this info to my post so you can see how it would work.

Comment: I've found a bug in most of popular editors - bug with coloring text in Opera. This bug is not their fault - it is fault of "execComand" built-in function that they use. Only tinyMCE has fixed this bug. Here in Russia - Opera is very popular browser, so I think I should move to tinyMCE editor (but it is very huge, i'd try to enlight it).

Comment: I didn't know Opera ran on the Timex/Sinclair! (just kidding)